# Checking if the uploaded file is really a proper file or not (php)

Tags: php, image, file, upload

Do the following steps to Understand the problem clearly :

1. Open notepad.
2. Type something and save it as " .png " (or any other image format).
3. Try to upload it as a image file with extension validation.
4. Now try to display it.

Expected : To show error while uploading

Actual : The file gets easily uploaded without any problem and error occurs only while accessing it.

Comment: so u r question is how to check a for a file content ?

Comment: You should check for file [mime_content_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) before upload.

Comment: Open the image in php with gd or a similar library and try to re-encode it (e.g. convert to jpg) - if it fails it is not a correct image.

Comment: @MihaiIorga mime type based solutions are inherently insecure because they can be easily spoofed.

Comment: @l4mpi yes, but there is no other *secure* alternative.

Comment: In the case of images, I stated the secure solution above - simply reencode the image. This removes any payload the file might contain and is secure as long as the image library is secure (and if it isn't, allowing any image to be uploaded is by itself insecure).

Answer (score 0):

mime_content_type() is deprecated function.
instead you can use

```
<?php
print_r(getimagesize("listing.png"));
?>
```

if this shows error then the file is invalid png file. If file is valid it returns an array of information.

Edit: This works if you are working with images only.

Comment: And when you are not dealing with images, use [`FileInfo functions`](http://php.net/ref.fileinfo)

Comment: @Carlos, yes but FileInfo is available via PECL, its not bundled in default package I think.

Comment: It is by default since php 5.3: "This extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0. Before this time, fileinfo was a PECL extension but is no longer maintained there. However, versions prior to 5.3+ may use the discontinued PECL extension."